# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Theme

Tags: themes, edubuntu

I've install human-theme_0.39.2_all.deb
But don't see any effect , theme doesn't added current listed themes in settings: Appearance:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) to use installed themes.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how to download Unity Tweak Tool haven't any link there .

Comment: @user73898 From the Ubuntu Software Centre...

Answer (score 1):

you can install ubuntu-tweak & manage your themes & icons & .... on unity or any other environment

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa -y

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak -y
```